# Who is Patchai ("Gitan")?

Tags: where-are-they-now

In 1999 the song *Gitan* by Patchai was a big hit in Europe, being featured on all the major pop compilations. [Here is the music video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TcVLTlN77KI).

This is gypsy-themed folk pop in Spanish. Patchai, a young boy, remained a one-hit wonder.

There is a much older, well-known Spanish gypsy musician, or "gitan", of the same name: Patchai Reyes, one of the three "Gypsy Kings" brothers.

(I don't know if it is a coincidence, but exactly while *Gitan* was big, the gypsy kings were also present [on the same major pop compilations](https://bravo-archiv.de/nmimage.php?z=bravohits/bravohits26back.jpg&width=900&height=700&title=BRAVO-Hits%2026) (disc 1, tracks 7 & 9) due to a collaboration with eurodance act Captain Jack.)

Does the boy Patchai have anything to do with the Gypsy kings? Who is he, and what became of him?

Comment: You can find references to an album in 2000 but it's hard to find reliable sources. You can also note that the composer of the *Gitan* hit is Chico, another Gipsy King.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The young Patchaï appears to be the son of Solange Reyes, the sister of the Reyes brothers of the [Gipsy Kings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gipsy_Kings). Canut Reyes writes on his [blog](http://francoiscanutreyes.blogspot.com/2011/04/petit-pachai.html) about another clip featuring his nephew:

There's also a clip of the six year old Patchaï singing with the whole family. At the end his uncle Nicolas says the boy started singing at the age of four.

He appears not to have stayed in the music business: his uncle Patchaï started a [new band](https://www.laprovence.com/article/papier/2992136/patchai-et-ses-gipsys-une-histoire-de-famille.html)  with his sons and nephews, and Patchaï Jr. is not in it.

Comment: There was also a concert apparently with Szandi and Patchai 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kiFMzQevKN8